# Get the text from Html.DropdownListFor....MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model:

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DocumentTypes { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TypeID, Model.DocumentTypes, "- please select -")
```

I populate my drop down

```
        var model = new DocumentModel();
        model.DocumentTypes = GetDocumentTypes(); 

private static List<SelectListItem> GetDocumentTypes()
    {

        var items = new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem
                                {Text = @"Text #1", Value = "1"},
                            new SelectListItem
                                {Text = @"Text #2", Value = "2"},
                        };

        return items;

    }
```

I have a controller action when the form is posted back:

```
 [HttpPost] 
    public void UploadDocument(DocumentModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // I want to get the text from the dropdown
        }
    }
```

How do i get the text from my drop down list? Thanks

Comment: did you want to retrieve selected item?

Comment: I believe that on a form submit containing a dropdown list, only the selected `VALUE` is sent. You could take the value and look up the text from the list, or you could expand and plan for it and pass it in a` @Html.HiddenFor()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may not get this easily with the default model binding. You have to a small workaround like this.

**1)** Add a new property to your model/viewmodel to store the selected text

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DocumentTypes { get; set; }
    public string SelctedType { set;get;}
}
```

**2)** Use `Html.HiddenFor` Helper method to create a hidden variable in the form for this property

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelctedType)
```

**3)** Use little javascript to override the submit ! ie; When user submits the form, Get the selected Text from the dropdown and set that value as the value of the Hidden field.

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var selTypeText= $("#TypeID option:selected").text();
        $("#SelctedType").val(selTypeText);           
    });
});
```

Now in your `HTTPPost` action method, This will be available in the `SelectedType` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadDocument(DocumentModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      string thatValue=model.SelectedType;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank for responding, but model.SelectedType is null when UploadDocument is called. Im still missing something

Comment: @user1202717: Use an alert in Step 3 before submitting the form(just after setting the hidden field value) to see whether you set it correctly

Comment: It works. I see you changed this line 'var selTypeText= $("#TypeID option:selected").text();' Man i cant believe dropdowns are such a pain in mVC. Thanks

Comment: @user1202717:You are most welcome ! :)  Yea. I copied from an example i tried. That is y it was initially with a diff name.  Glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

if what you want to do is to retrieve selected item then this can do the work :

```
  var selecteItem = model.DocumentTypes.Where(item=>item.Selected).FirstOrDefault();
```

Cheers!

Comment: I run this and selectedItem is null

Answer (score 1):

On your model I would have another string -

```
public string Selected{ get; set; }
```

then in your view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selected, new SelectList(Model.DocumentTypes, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: I tried this and ran this line of code 'var selecteItem = model.DocumentTypes.Where(item=>item.Selected).FirstOrDefault();' and selectedItem is still null

Comment: You should not have needed the var etc stuff.  In your controller you should have simply been able to do string selected = model.Selected; If you then had a break point on the next line the string selected should have the value from the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled here trying to find the way to get the text value out of a SelectList to display it in a format other than a DropDownList (I'm reusing my Edit ViewModel as it has all the data I required)

```
var text = selectList.Where(q => q.Selected == true).First().Text;
```