# how to bind dropdownlist selecteditem and its corresponding text value to the database- update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am beginner to MVC5 and learning on the go. I have a dropdownlist whose values are binded to the view from the database as follows:​

[image]

How to pass the values of the selected item from the dropdownlist along with the corresponding text value to the database? a simple example will be fine.

here is the update for Question. I have included my code

mycontroller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetQuestions()
    {
        var getQuestions = service.GetListOfQuestions().ToList();
        ViewBag.questions_drpdwn = new SelectList(getQuestions, "Id", "Question");
        return View();
    }`
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmEmail", "CreateAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })){
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.questions_drpdwn,"-- Select a Question--")
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Answer)
<div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
 </div>
```

}

Model

```
public class QuestionsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     

    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public string SelctedType { set; get; }
}
```

I am trying to post back the selecteditem from dropdownlist(i.e question) and its corresponding textboxvalue(i.e answer) to the model.

Comment: Is the dropdown created using the HTML Helper or are you using straight HTML5?

Comment: html helper - @html.DropDownListFor

Comment: Yeah the work around is complex, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034892/get-the-text-from-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc3 . Best way is just pure HTML5 though, but if you want to stick to Models that's yourr best bet. m

Answer (score 1):

For WebForms, the dropdownlist can have the autopostback thing.

For MVC, you need to use javascript to detect the changes in dropdownlist and use ajax to postback the value to server.

Here is an example using jquery to do the postback

```
$("#DropDown").bind('change', function () {
    var id = $("#DropDown option:selected").val();
    var text = $("#DropDown  option:selected").text();  

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/MethodName?id=' + id + "&text=" + text,
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function (result) {
        //Do something with the result
    })
});
```

If you use normal HttpPost (submit form),

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmEmail(QuestionsViewModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Do something here
   }

   return View(model);
}
```

The returned model will have Id as the selected value of your dropdownlist and Answer as value of your textbox. Question and SelectedType will be null.

I think it is better if you learn more basic of MVC first.

[Getting started with MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: You don't **need** to use ajax (although you can)

Comment: Thanks for the post, I am planning to do on the model, is there any example on that? thanks, much appreciated